# Solving a linear system of matrix equations in GF(2) using Sage

Tags: finite-fields, matrix-equations, sagemath

I am trying to solve a system of two equations of the form:

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
K_1XC + K_2YC & = V_1 \\
K_3XC + K_4YC & = V_2 \\
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

where the $K_i$ and $V_i$ are constants, $C$ a "counting" vector filled with 1, and $X, Y$ diagonal matrices with the unknowns on the diagonal. All matrices coefficients are in $GF(2)$.

I tried to implement them using Sage like this:

```
R = PolynomialRing(GF(2), 64, "x")

X = diagonal_matrix(R.gens()[:32])
Y = diagonal_matrix(R.gens()[32:])

K1 = matrix.zero(R, 32)
# filling K1...
# same for K2, K3, K4

C = matrix.ones(R, 32, 1)
```

At this point, printing $K_1XC + K_2YC$ give me a huge column vector containing the equations I want. However, I am failing to find how to solve them.

```
sol = solve([K1*X*C + K2*Y*C == V1, K3*X*C + K4*Y*C == V2], [variables?])
```

throws me an error message no matter what I try, mostly `TypeError: x0 is not a valid variable.` and the likes.

[This link](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8906/members-of-a-polynomial-ring-dont-respond-to-solve/) advised to declare my 64 variables in the symbolic ring SR, which give me a `TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for *: 'Finite Field of size 2' and 'Symbolic Ring'`. It also explains that the resolution of such a system needs ideals and term orders, which I never heard of and seem above my math level.

How should I proceed to solve my system?

Comment: You are conflating some mathematical and programming problems. You should try to simplify the mathematics first, which is just linear algebra, and then try to use sage in a more standard way using linear algebra tools. Let $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)^T$, where $n = 32$. Then your matrix product $XC$ is just $x$. Similarly $YC = y$. Let $z = (x; y)$ and $v = (V_1; V_2)$, and let $K = (K_1, K_2; K_3, K_4)$. Then your equation is just $Kz = v$. Here is a reference for linear algebra in sage: https://wiki.sagemath.org/quickref?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=quickref-linalg.pdf

Comment: @SeanEberhard Indeed, I was too focused on Sage and did not notice the system could be simplified to this much easier form. It is solved now. Thank you.